# Trying to customize wordpress drop down categories

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm having some problems on how to display the categories that i want in wp_dropdown_categories.

Here is an image of the drop down -

http://i255.photobucket.com/albums/hh140/testament1234/customizeddropdown_zps8d2fe3c7.png

Here is the code for the dropdown -

**HTML:**

```
<?php wp_dropdown_categories( $args ); ?>
```

**JS:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var dropdown = document.getElementById("cat");
function onCatChange() {
    if ( dropdown.options[dropdown.selectedIndex].value > 0 ) {
        location.href = "<?php echo get_option('home');
?>/?cat="+dropdown.options[dropdown.selectedIndex].value;
    }
}
dropdown.onchange = onCatChange;
</script>
```

I tried placing this code in my functions.php and customize it but it doesn't seem to work.

```
<?php $args = array(
'show_option_all'    => '',
'show_option_none'   => '',
'orderby'            => 'ID', 
'order'              => 'ASC',
'show_count'         => 0,
'hide_empty'         => 1, 
'child_of'           => 0,
'exclude'            => '',
'echo'               => 1,
'selected'           => 0,
'hierarchical'       => 0, 
'name'               => 'cat',
'id'                 => '',
'class'              => 'postform',
'depth'              => 0,
'tab_index'          => 0,
'taxonomy'           => 'category',
'hide_if_empty'      => false,
    'walker'             => ''
); ?>
```

Comment: Define "not working". Have you check in console if any error in js?

Comment: the drop down is working and it has no problems when i use firebug. What i'm looking for is how i can display the categories that i only want in the drop down

Comment: Which categories you want to exclude from dropdown ?

Comment: example is the "Uncategorized" or the Featured Post. I have placed an image on top which is my work in progress. Basically i just want the drop down to display specific categories.

Comment: just give exclude category id's in exclude parameter of $args eg: `'exclude' => '0,1'`. Taking here 0 for Uncategorized & 1 is for feature products.

Comment: Thanks. Your answered work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this we have exclude params in $arg of [wp_dropdown_categories](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_dropdown_categories).
Just give exclude category id's in exclude parameter in $args array as below,

```
'exclude' => '0,1'
```

Taking here 0 for Uncategorized & 1 is for feature products.